# Programmatically remove content from a group

Tags: 8, nodes, group

In order to add a node to any group in Drupal 8, I use the following code.

```
$group->addContent($node, 'group_node:article');
```

Now, for removing content from a group, I have tried `$group->removeContent($node, 'group_node:article');` and `$group->removeContent($node);` without success. All I obtained is the following error message.

> Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\group\Entity\Group::removeContent() in Drupal\my_valetop_extras\Plugin\WebformHandler\CustomWebformHandler->submitForm()

Finally, I have managed to remove content from a group using this code.

```
$type = 'group_node:' . $node->getType();
$current_node = $group->getContent($type, ['entity_id' => $node_id]);
$content = array_values($current_node)[0];
$content->delete();
```

But  believe I can remove a single node from a group with a simple line of code.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that function was overlooked by the developers. In the issues queue for the [Group module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/group), which is what your error message refers to, I can see that the inverse of `addMember()`, `removeMember()`, [was added later in the project's life](https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/2846740). It seems reasonable to suppose that the inverse of `addContent()` was also overlooked, with the only difference being that it has remained unimplemented to this day.

There are no functions with names hinting at content-removing behaviour evident in the module's [GroupInterface definition](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/group/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Entity/GroupInterface.php), so I recommend opening a new issue with the project to let them know about the gap.

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach for programmatically adding and removing a node from a group on update. A `removeContent()` function would be helpful. However for my situation, I had to check if the entity was in the Group anyways, which gave me the GroupContent object that I could delete to remove the entity from the group.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update().
 */
function hook_node_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
    ...
    if (!empty($group = Group::load(1))) {
      $type = 'group_node:' . $entity->getType();
      $group_content = false;
      // Search for this entity in the group.
      $group_content_search = $group->getContent($type, ['entity_id' => $entity->id()]);
      if (!empty($group_content_search)) {
        $group_content = reset($group_content_search);
      }
    
      // Add entity to group.
      $group->addContent($entity, $type);

      ...
    
      // Remove entity from group.
      if (!empty($group_content)) {
        $group_content->delete();
      }
    }
    ...
```